# Positioning HTML buttons using CSS

Tags: html, css

So far I have got 3 buttons displaying in the browser which all use the same CSS code. 
However they are placed right under an image in the heading and parts of the button is cut off.
I'm trying to position 3 buttons in the center of the page and with equal spacing.

CSS code for the butttons:

```
.btn {
   background: #3498db;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
   font-family: Arial;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 25px;
   padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
   background: #3cb0fd;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML code displaying the 3 buttons:

```
<button class="btn">Entry forms</button>
<button class="btn">Scoresheets</button>
<button class="btn">Results</button>
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of HTML/CSS...

Comment: Can you provide a not-working example, like on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5prdmmak/

Comment: "parts of the button is cut off" we need to see the other elements HTML and CSS

Comment: If the buttons are in a container element, then it isn't big enough to fit the buttons.   Make the container bigger or the buttons smaller.

Comment: @Danko I have an image in the header and its cutting over the buttons, I need to move them down to the middle of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping wrapping your buttons in a `div` with the style `text-align: center`.

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5prdmmak/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your three `<buttons>`'s inside a `<div>` and assign `text-align: center` to that `<div>`. Moreover, to add an equal space between the three buttons, you can add `margin-right: 10px;` to `.btn:first-child, .btn:nth-child(2)` using CSS.

```css
.btn {
        background: #3498db;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 25px;
        padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .btn:hover {
        background: #3cb0fd;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
        text-decoration: none;
    }
#buttons {
    text-align: center;
}

.btn:first-child, .btn:nth-child(2)  {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<center><img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150" /></center>
<div id="buttons"><button class="btn">Entry forms</button>
<button class="btn">Scoresheets</button>
<button class="btn">Results</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a div with text-align: center

```
<div style="text-align:center;"> 
<button class="btn">Entry forms</button>
<button class="btn">Scoresheets</button>
<button class="btn">Results</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the code to a div, as mentioned, or to a table with

```
<table style="text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      first_button_data_here
    </td>
    <td>
      second_button_data_here
    </td>
    <td>
      third_button_data_here
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```